# I cant seem to retrieve regular expression stored in database - php

Tags: php, mysql, regex, arrays

So I am having a bit of an issue getting results from a query.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT re_diag_DL
          FROM game_win_regex 
          WHERE game_id = 1
          LIMIT 1";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost",'root','','game');
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
echo $row['re_diag_DL'][0];
?>
```

The fields content is a regular expression:

```
((?<!z,)[1]
```

But the echo is giving

```
((?
```

It is definitely messing with the array structure, a print_r() gives

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ((?
```

I intend to use this result within a preg_match_all. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `echo htmlspecialchars($row['re_diag_DL'][0],ENT_QUOTES);`  Use the htmlspecialchars function to convert special HTML characters for display in a web page. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the echoing is being done in a web browser and the browser is expecting a tag starting with `<`.

Check the source code of the page, not the rendered page.

By the way, you can safely use the result of `$row['re_diag_DL'][0]` in a `preg_match_all` as it is merely a display issue.

Answer (score 0):

To view in the browser use htmlentities().  As Mosty Mostacho states, the browser treats < and > as HTML tags and doesn't display them as text.

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
```

in the begin of php-file. Or view source of HTML document. Or wrap in PRE tag. You regexp was treated by browser as html tag.

Comment: `<pre>` will only make it display line breaks and extra spaces, it won't make it display tags.